# OpenGL errors on A7-devices in iOS 10

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, ios10

My image processing app behaves really strange on devices with an A7 chip (iPhone 5s and iPad Mini 2 tested) after the update to iOS 10:

Rendering takes extremely long and produces broken results. Instruments reveals that some of the `glDrawElements` calls return with `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. I couldn't make out the cause for that, though.

The same code runs perfectly fine on newer devices (A8 and better) and on all devices in iOS 9. Did Apple change things I am not aware of?

Some more background info:

- I'm partially using textures of `GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES` type
- I make use of the `EXT_color_buffer_half_float` extension to render into those textures
- I use the `EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch` extension to process pixels in some of my filters in-place

Comment: Have you tried tracing the error in the [Xcode GPU Frame Capture tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ToolsOverview/ToolsOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-A2-SW1)? That might help narrow down the cause of the error.

Comment: @rickster I used the "OpenGL ES Analysis" instrument, which does basically the same but over the whole runtime. It helped me narrow down the cause to the `glDrawElements` call. The Frame Capture Tool seem to sample the next few frames, which works great if you have a continuous render loop, but not if you render on demand.

Comment: Frame capture samples all the calls that go into a *single* frame,  shows details on all the GL state you've set as of each bind/draw/etc call, and shows warnings more detailed than "invalid operation" when there's something wrong. You can trigger a capture programmatically at the end of a render pass, so you don't have to worry about on-demand rendering making it hard to time a capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I was only partially assigning `gl_FragColor` in some of my shaders (e.g., `gl_FragColor.rg = vec2(1.0, 0.0);`), which caused the erroneous behavior in iOS 10. Possibly only in combination with a `GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES`-typed render target, though.

When I always assign the full vector (even though the other parts are unused…), it works like a charm.

Comment: On a site note: WTF Apple?!

Comment: OpenGL ES seems to be implemented on top of Metal in iOS 10 so some teething problems are not completely unexpected (r.e. WTF comment).